What am I seeing while closing my eyes?
We all must have noticed that when we close our eyes or rub them with our hands we generally see some patterns,shapes or colors. I am still unable to understand what are these things called and whe do we see them. I tried to search on the net but I really don't know what to search. Is there a scientific explanation of this phenomenon and what are these things called?
Help is appreciated

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics

These patterns are generally called phosphenes. They can be caused by a variety of different things, including mechanical stimulation (such as from rubbing your eyes, where the pressure directly stimulates cells in your retina).
